# Servlet working locally, but on dedicated server blank page

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app>
  <display-name>Ajax uploader</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <display-name>UploadFile</display-name>
    <servlet-name>UploadFile</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.fileupload.UploadFile</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>UploadFile</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/UploadFile</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

JSP:

```
<form id="UploadForm" action="UploadFile" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Perfect working on localhost, but on dedicated tomcat:

> blank page

Location seems legit:

> /uploader/WEB-INF/classes/com/fileupload/UploadFile.class

No error logs in catalina.out

Comment: From the web.xml, your URL should be https://***/UploadFile/UploadFile

Comment: I changed JDK to 7 (error from catalina.out). Now it's blank page. Calling  https://***/UploadFile/UploadFile returns 404

Comment: Try http instead of https. If you get a blank page, hit F12 in your browser and check your your response status (if it's 200 it seems that your page returns nothing)

Comment: check you war file by opening it in some compression tools and check for servlet class. If file is present in war  . open webapps directory of the tomcat and see to it that file is in proper loacation ie, web-inf/classes/.../../

Comment: Unless you have changed the context of your app, the URL should be `http://***/uploader/UploadFile` (or with https, depends on your config, *** means your server address (and port, if needed)).

Comment: okay, calling servlet from jsp form still provides blank page, but going directly returns 405 HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL

Comment: Everything is working now. Thanks for help!